# My url patterns in urls.py in Django do not match

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu

This is my views.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
from search.models import Keywords
#from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rr

def front_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        str1 = request.POST['word'] 
        fo = open("xml.txt","r")
        for i in range(count.__len__()):

             file = fo.readline()
             file = file.rstrip('\n')
             find_root_tags(file,str1,i)    

             list.append((file,count[i]))

             sorting_list(list)

        for name, count in list:
            s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count)
            s.save()

        fo.close()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/')

    else :  
        str1 = ''
        list = []
        template = loader.get_template('search/search.html')
        c = RequestContext(request)
        response = template.render(c)
        return HttpResponse(response)

def results(request):

    list1 = Keywords.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template('search/results.html')
    c = Context({'list1':list1,
    })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

this is my results.html(which is stored in /home/pooja/Desktop/my_templates/search/results.html, 
(here search is my app name) :

```
<html>
<body bgcolor = "#9ACD32">
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
         position: absolute;
         top:   200px;
         left:  480px;
       }    

form #Edit1 { position: relative; 
              top: 245px; 
              left:   480px; 
            }

form #Edit2 { position: relative; 
              top:    220px; 
              left:   680px; 
            }
</style>
<font size="5" face="arial" color="#0000FF">
<h1>Search Page</h1>
</font>
<hr/>
<br/>
<br/>
<Form Method ="POST">
<div id="Edit1">
<INPUT TYPE = 'text'  name ='word' VALUE ="">
</div>
<div id="Edit2">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "Search">
</div>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran this app on server, the search.html page was coming and as I entered some word say 'book' it gave me this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns,in this order:
^search/$
^admin/
The current URL, front_page/, didn't match any of these.
```

Why has this happened? I have my all the skey.py, xml documents and xml.txt stored in search app.

Comment: Seriously, what was the point of pasting all that code? The error should be obvious: you haven't got a URL that matches `front_page`. What is your actual question?

Comment: Look in mysite.urls.py you need to point say /$ to 'front_page' in views.py.
Add a line like `url(r'^$', 'front_page'),`

Answer (score 0):

The action on the form is `/front_page/`. If you want it to go to the current URL then you should omit the `action` attribute altogether.